# typescript model adding mongoose authentication

Tags: typescript, authentication, mongoose, restful-authentication

my problem is when I try to add mongoose passport to my schema I got error message:

```
export interface IUserModel extends IUser, Document { };

export let userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
}

firstName: { type: String, required: true },
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
export let User: Model<IUserModel> = model<IUserModel>("User", userSchema);
```

I add to app.ts ( main file ):

```
import { User } from "./schemas/user";
let passport = require("passport");
passport.use(new localstrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

Then I got error message:

**error TS2339: Property `authenticate` does not exist on type `Model<IUserModel>`**

please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation that states that mongoose Model has .authenticate() method?

Comment: as far as I know the require("passport-local-mongoose"), will provide this plugin.

Comment: @libik what do you think about this: i will replace mongoose authentication with jwt?

Comment: Ah thanks, maybe I know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Typescript basically does not know that something injected into some other module some extra values.

I have been solving similar problem in express. To express `req: express.Request` I need to inject `state`, so I can use my custom `req.state` through my middlewares.

This is the hack:

```
import { State } from './index';

declare module 'express' {
    interface Request {
        state: State;
    }
}
```

(the State is just Typescript model):

```
export type State = {
    correlationId?: string;
    sessionId?: string;
    logger: Logger;
    out: any;
};
```

I think you can do something like (lets try it, if not working, fix it and if you make it working, please write the correct solution, so others can use it)

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
    interface Model {
        authenticate: Function;
    }
}
```

---

Also there is one "hacky" solution - just save it to `:any` variable and then use it, typescript do not control anything with it (which on the other hand is also not perfect as you lose some advantage of using typescript - but if it is only for small part of app, you can do it)

```
import { User } from "./schemas/user";
let passport = require("passport");
const userThatCanDoAnything: any = User;
passport.use(new localstrategy(userThatCanDoAnything.authenticate()));
```